`git pull` but don't error when branch doesn't exist in remote
I have a GitHub workflow that builds my static site from the main branch and pushes the build into the static branch. Basically, what it does is this:
# Clone the main branch
# ...

# Build the site to the `output/` directory
# ...

# Minimal git config required for push
git config --global user.name 'My Name'
git config --global user.email 'myname@example.com'
git config --global push.autoSetupRemote true

# Switch to the static branch, creating it if it doesn't exist
git switch -C static

# *

# Add and commit the output/ directory (use -f because it is in .gitignore)
git add -f output/
git commit -m "Automatic site build: $(date)"

# Push
git push

This script worked perfectly fine on the first run. However, the second time I ran it,
it failed on git push with the fetch first error, because the remote static branch contains the outputs of the last build and the main branch doesn't know about that.
One way to fix this, I think, would be to insert git pull at the point marked # *, but that will cause the script to fail on the first run if it is reused in another repo, because the static branch was just created and doesn't have its remote set up yet (note that there is no pull.autoSetupRemote counterpart to push.autoSetupRemote in git config).
So, what I really want to do is insert a command like if [branch static exists in remote]; git pull; end.

Can I make such a command?
Is doing so the best way to solve my problem?

Note: My question is not about GitHub pages.

Do you need to keep the history of static? If you don't you could force push.

if git ls-remote --exit-code origin static; then
    git pull
fi

See the docs.

This errors with There is no tracking information for the current branch (even after changing git switch -C to git switch -c)

@Max Do you prefer git pull origin static or git fetch origin && git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/static && git pull?
